# I call Api in react native every time get Network Error how to Fix it?

Tags: react-native

I am new in React Native Development. I had call Login Api it's every time give me Network error. How to fixed it? Please help me below is my code.

```
const config = {
                method: 'post',
                url: BASE_URL+"/auth/login",
                headers: {        
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                data: {
                        username: "physician@doral.com",
                        password: "password",
                        device_token: "",
                        device_type: 1,
                        latitude: "",
                        longitude: ""
                      }
              };
        
             axios(config)    
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
          
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err :", err); 
                Alert.alert("something went to wrong.",err.message);    
              });
```

I have try using fetch and Axios but get same result. please help me how to fixed and get proper response of this api.

Comment: is your `BASE_URL` localhost` or it's plain uri?, and also does your `BASE_URL` uses `https`?

Comment: https://api.doralhealthconnect.com/api this my base url. yes i have use https

Comment: is this problem occurring on IOS or Android?

Comment: android real device

Comment: Have u tried this ? "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Accept: "application/json"

Comment: Also try to change `url: BASE_URL+"/auth/login" --> to url: BASE_URL+"/auth/login/"` add slash at the end of endpoint,

Comment: yes i have checked but same error show me.

Comment: I have checked both flow which you tell in comment but show me network error. please tell me how to fix it?